# Equivalent of UIBarButtonSystemItemAction for Android?

Tags: android

On iOS devices the icon UIBarButtonSystemItemAction (a rounded rectangle with an arrow coming out of the middle and bending to the top right, Google image search shows examples) is used to e.g. open a document in another application. What is the equivalent icon for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon resource used for sharing action (which seems close to `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction`) is `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share`. Please read [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) to understand the conventions and design decisions you should make while porting an application from other platforms to Android.

Someone has compiled a list of [`android.R.drawable icon` resources](http://www.darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html). You can check the available drawable resources yourselves following the tutorial [here](http://mgmblog.com/2008/12/12/listing-androids-drawable-resources/).